# how to update multiple services at the same time in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

`docker service update --force --image ${image} ${service}` will update only one service, but I have several services that rely on a same image and I need to update them simultaneously.

Comment: Is there any reason you need multiple services of the same image rather than using one service and scaling it up to the same number of replicas as you have services today? That way you would only need to update your one service, and all the containers that are part of the service, no matter on which node they are located, would be updated to use the new image.

Comment: One service for django backend, another service for celery worker. They share same source code and that why have same image.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a script like

```
docker service update -d service1
docker service update -d service2
...
```

`-d`, the detached mode, makes the command exit immediately, so in the background your services will be updated at the same time.

Comment: and docker machine will not put them in queue and call one by one?

Comment: @Aiven they’re executed concurrently, same way as if you do ‘docker stack deploy ‘

Comment: is there a way to check is service converged successfully in detached mode? (beside checking `docker ps` / `docker service ls` from time to time)

Comment: unfortunately no, you would have to do it manually, but if you have a good rollback policy, a failure will not result in server downtime, so it's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Using swarm mode, you can update all services that are part of the stack at once

`docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml <stack-name>`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/

Comment: `docker stack deploy` is overkill :) That's why I use `service update`

Comment: This only updates containers that have an updated image.

Comment: @Aiven, actually, it's not. The command will update all the services with the latest images version

Comment: My pain point with that command for update is that it resets the number of replicas I scaled after deploying the stack.

Comment: @WildDev do I need to add something to the compose file? Because in my experience `stack deploy` always reload everything. I can see it in logs and with `service ls` (if I run it right after redeploy)

Comment: How about specifying a version tag on the images that don't need to be updated. This way, if you run a stack deploy, only the images with the latest tag will be updated, and the images with specific version tags wont be.

Comment: @Aiven, you can update either entire swarm or particular service. Guess, you'll have to update related services manually, once the stack update is not desired

Comment: This is subject to issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31357